# What does this error mean? "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Test Page"

Tags: website, homepage

When I visit http://www.mycompwebsite.com/ I get this page:

[image: Front page]

I dont know why I am getting this. How cna I get rid of this?

Comment: Obviously that's **WAY** too much text for you to actually read, but if you got around to it, you'd notice that it's actually a set of instructions telling you exactly what do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look what it says on the right-hand column:

> You may now add content to the
>   directory `/var/www/html/`... follow
>   the instructions in the file
>   `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`

I suggest you heed its advice

Comment: @Farseeker already there are contents in the file..

Comment: @Farseeker there is no such folder `/var/www/html/` as my server is ubuntu.... When i used ftp client and my user name and password there is `htdocs` folder and there my files are hosted...

Comment: If that's the case, then I would suspect that your DNS entry for your domain name is incorrect, and you're actually looking at completely the wrong server. If you're running Ubuntu, but you're seeing the RHEL welcome page, and the folders don't exist, then it's higly plausible that the request isn't even getting to your server.

Answer (score 3):

As the error states in the right hand column there is no content in the */var/www/html* directory. The web server will display this page as long as you don't replace it from the */var/www/html* directory.

This is the document root or the point where your website is hosted. If you this isn't on your computer, contact the site admin to put up content or wait :)

Comment: Didn't see your answer while I was replying @Farseeker. @Pandiya, are you looking at the contents of the same /var/www/html that you are trying to access through the browser? 

If your local machine is ubuntu and you are trying to access the same machine through browser, it shouldn't be displaying a redhat error page...unless there is some redirection happening.

Comment: my local system is windows xp... And my website is hosted in an ubuntu server...

Comment: If your website is hosted on an ubuntu server and you have contents in your document root up there, maybe some weird redirection is happening. Check the contents of the files in your document root or ask the sysadmin at the server to check Apache configuration.

Comment: definitely ll do that...